# Salt: 'dockerng' __virtual__ returned False

Tags: docker, salt-stack

I have Debian Jessie and I'm trying to manage Docker containers with [Salt](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/) [dockerng](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.dockerng.html). But when I try for example this state:

```
# file: docker_demo.sls

hello-world:
  dockerng.image_present
```

Then `sudo salt '*' state.highstate` fails:

```
----------
          ID: hello-world
    Function: dockerng.image_present
      Result: False
     Comment: State 'dockerng.image_present' was not found in SLS 'docker_demo'
              Reason: 'dockerng' __virtual__ returned False
     Started: 
    Duration: 
     Changes:
```

How can I fix this so `dockerng.image_present` can pull the image, `dockerng.running` can run Docker containers etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dockerng module executed by Salt minion communicates with Docker daemon over REST API using [docker-py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/docker-py) (not the CLI command `docker`).

The error message `'dockerng' __virtual__ returned False` is a little bit misleading, but if you see the source code, it returns `False` because it cannot import Pyhon module `docker`. So this Python package must be installed.

There are packages in Debian repository: `python-docker` and `python3-docker`. But both are incompatible with the recent `docker-engine` (installed from APT repository `deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo debian-jessie`).

So the solution is to uninstall `python-docker` package if installed and to install the latest `docker-py` using `pip`:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install docker-py
```

Or use this Salt state:

```
python-pip:
  pkg.installed

docker-py:
  pip.installed:
    - require:
      - pkg: python-pip
```

Or just run

```
salt myminion pip.install docker-py
```

---

The `python-docker` package from **Debian Stretch** (now testing, should become Debian stable in 2017) seems to be working OK.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. I have ```docker-py==1.2.3``` installed, but this doesn't help

Comment: @VitalyIsaev But current version of `docker-py` is 1.5.0: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/docker-py Can you try it?

Comment: you're right. I've notticed that minimal ```docker-py``` version is 1.4.0. It's a big pity because we're running ```docker 1.6``` on our servers and we cannot move to more recent ```docker-py```